# C# Regular Expression, Match contents of string

Tags: c#, regex

i am trying to capture the text in the inverted commas in the following string using c# regular expresions.

I've tried a whole lot of patterns but none of them are matching..

Can anyone help?

```
text1.text2 = text3["THISISWHATIWANTTOCAPTURE"].text4();
```

Comment: Note: I don't care if the inverted commas are part of the match or not.

Comment: Have tried so many, this was the last one... Regex regex = new Regex(".*\"(.*)\".*");

Comment: They're called "double quotes".

Comment: @Michael: We programmers may call them *double quotes*, but normal people call them *inverted commas* in Europe and *quotation marks* in the US. ;)

Comment: @Alan: learn something new every day. I'd question the nonsensical-to-my-ears "inverted commas", but then we'd get into a whole "why do we drive on a parkway, and park on a driveway" discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest expression I'd come up with is

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+\["(.+)"\]
```

Answer (score 2):

This one will do it:

```
(?<=\").*(?=\")
```

You can test the above regex here:

http://regexhero.net/tester/

In C#:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pattern = "(?<=\").*(?=\")";
        string str =
        "text1.text2 = text3[\"THISISWHATIWANTTOCAPTURE\"].text4();";

        Match match = Regex.Match(str, pattern);

        foreach (var c in match.Captures)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
THISISWHATIWANTTOCAPTURE
```

Comment: Has multiple captured groups. OP wants to capture only `THISISWHATIWANTTOCAPTURE`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(string, @"\"([^\"]+)\"");
```